# Native toast message on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Can you help me give a library that have notification feature like on **Web Slack** and **Web Skype** that can notify user even if he/she is not on your site page. [image: Just like this image]
Thanks, sorry for the title I dont know what type of notification this is.

Answer (score 1):

This is either a chrome extension or a native app, a browser window can't normally access other windows

Their documentation sucks, I would recommend just searching around stack overflow

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

If, by the chance this is actually a new thing, it would be called a web-worker, which is a long running process behind the scenes. Likely, it's a background script which uses some chrome API

Comment: how about on other browser sir?

Comment: i dont know much about the other browsers, but it's possible they have similar hooks. iOS safari does not support extensions, only bookmarklets, and they havent approved or denied web workers (it takes away power from their app store)

Comment: This is a really good question. I am so curious to find out how they did it, as specially since I did not install any extensions.

Answer (score 0):

*I know this question was asked ages ago, but this turned up when I googled a similar question. So thought I would share the correct links...*

The official documentation for this is:

**Chrome**
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/

**Safari**
https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/

**Firefox**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API